# Measuring the on and off time of a of a pulse in C#

Tags: math, c#-4.0, fft

I am trying to determine when a low frequency digital signal is on and off. And once I can determine transitions accurately, measure the time on and the time off.

The signal is operating at andywhere from 0.5Hz to 5Hz. I get a sample about every 30ms. This is a floating point value that is generally very consistent once a transition has happened but is changing while the transition occurs. And, unfortunately, the transition is not instantaneous. There is sometimes 2 or 3 samples where the value is changing, and the sample value is never identical between samples there is always a little jitter.

I have tried taking a large number of samples, sorting them, get them mean and average the values below the mean to represent OFF and the average of the values about the mean to be ON. This worked, sort of, as the mean of 99 samples should be the 50th sample. Unfortunately, in the real world you cannot always get 49 values on either side of the mean that are perfect in the ON or OFF state.

So, is this something that I should be using a moving average or a exponential average on? A DFT? A FFT? I have also tried comparing the previous sample with the next sample and that is almost as good. But I am still having trouble getting an accurate value to say a transition has occurred.

An example would be:

The device is an "unknown" state, the samples look like this:

- S0 - 45.1156987295826
- S1 - 45.1156987295826
- S2 - 67.7942377495463
- S3 - 67.7942377495463
- S4 - 60.9886569872958
- S5 - 49.4682395644283
- S6 - 45.1156987295826

It is pretty easy to see that S0 and S1 are in the OFF state and S2 and S3 are in the ON state but S4 and S5 trend toward the OFF state but which state do S4 and S5 belong to? (FYI, the data is never this clean I am using a simulated device which transitions very very quickly)

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: show us the signal (idealy plot) without it we can not help ....

Comment: @Spektre : a plot won't help that much (could even be misleading) if the definition of a legal input signal could vary too much from what any one plot (or two) could show.

Comment: Thanks. A plot might be helpful. I will try to gen one.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I wanated to see the plot so I see the properties of signal. My bet is telling me abs difference between signal and its centered sliding average will detect the pulses robustly (with some basic thresholding) but to be sure we need some test data (7 points of signal is hardly enough)

Comment: Sorry, 7 points is very little data, I quite agree, I will try and post a larger set to see if someone has a better idea. At the moment I am using k-means clustering to find a point by which I can say the signal switched. It is proving to be more accurate than my other tries but I do not think this is the end-all-be-all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a low-pass filter, with a time-constant of around 0.5 seconds, to get rid of some of the jitter.  Then look for peaks in the 1st derivative of the low-pass filter result for the steepest portion of each onset.  Interpolate (quadratic or cubic) this peak between the the 1st difference samples, if necessary.

If you a-priori know the approximate size of the noise "jitter", you may still have to use a threshold above this jitter to prevent false positives.

Successive approximation: You could also set arbitrary thresholds; then examine the resulting transition decisions to see if they meet your signal definition criteria (all or most pulse widths between 0.5 and 5 Hz).  If not adjust the threshold up and down until your criteria is met (or maximized).  If you find a range of transition thresholds that work, pick the median for the greatest noise immunity.

Comment: I bumped this +1 but have work to do to understand your suggestions, though it is likely the answer is in here. I did try a K-means clustering today but I am still not convinced this is helping. Maybe a trend analysis is the right approach but there are very few data points. I will add an example of the data to my original post.